# WordPress 3.9 - Trouble Editing TinyMCE 4.0

Tags: filters, tinymce, editor

With WordPress 3.9 coming soon it's bringing along TinyMCE 4.0. I'm running my plugins and functions through some testing and found that one of my functions seems broken / not working with the new TinyMCE

```
function myformatTinyMCE( $in )
{
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons1'] = 'bold';
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons2'] = 'formatselect';
    $in['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = false;
    return $in; 
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
```

The above function used to limit the buttons in the tinyMCE to specific buttons, I've simplified it a bit to make it easier for testing. If I print out `$in` it shows the correct values in the correct spots, but when I actually load up a page it just defaults to the normal buttons.

I've also tried to use the example in the [TinyMCE Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) which also didn't seem to have any effect.

I'm using the [WordPress Beta Tester](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/) Plugin and I do have [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) installed but disabled.

With the new TinyMCE how can I continue using / customizing, and are there any 'Gotchas' that have changed from the previous TinyMCE Version?

**EDIT**

Looks like `$in['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = false;` is not longer being used - No idea how to unhide the Kitchen Sink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strings was new, not more for your requirements.

This is the new content of the hook.

```
array (
  'selector' => '#content',
  'resize' => 'vertical',
  'menubar' => false,
  'wpautop' => true,
  'indent' => false,
  'toolbar1' => 'template,|,bold,italic,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,blockquote,hr,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,wp_more,spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv',
  'toolbar2' => 'formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help',
  'toolbar3' => '',
  'toolbar4' => '',
  'tabfocus_elements' => 'insert-media-button,save-post',
  'body_class' => 'content post-type-post post-status-draft post-format-standard',
)
```

Also change the strings inside the array in your source to:

```
function myformatTinyMCE( $in ) {

    $in['toolbar1'] = 'bold';
    $in['toolbar2'] = 'formatselect';

    return $in; 
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
```

But see also this test plugin [Gist 9758082](https://gist.github.com/bueltge/9758082) and [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139163/add-custom-tinymce-4-button-usable-since-wordpress-3-9-beta1) for WP 3.9 and the new TinyMCE 4.0 to understand the topic.

#### Forcing Toolbar2

To show always the toolbar 2, without use the button `wp_adv` add the follow source to a plugin.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'fb_force_show_toolbar2' );
function fb_force_show_toolbar2() {
    set_user_setting( 'hidetb', 1 );
}
```

BUT, now the hint for the value `wordpress_adv_hidden`. In the next WordPress version, after 3.9 will restore the old hook `wordpress_adv_hidden` to toggle the toolbar, see [ticket 27963](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27963). Then is possible to to use the follow source. `$in['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = FALSE;`

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
function myformatTinyMCE( $in ) {

    $in['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = FALSE;

    return $in; 
}
```

Comment: So there's no unhiding the "kitchen sink" (toolbar2)?

Comment: What is the Kitchen sink?

Comment: Toolbar2, `wp_adv` - show toolbar1 and toolbar 2 by default. You used to be able to do this by `$in['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = false;` which no longer works.

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I have add the source to my answer to forcing the toolbar2.

Comment: I tried to use the update user settings but it didn't seem to do anything - [My Code Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mW2J3XsH) - I did get it to work using [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220980/wordpress-tinymce-buttons) with the `auth_redirect` hook instead.

Comment: `auth_redirect` fired earlier, not more. You can also use `init` or `plugins_loaded`; maybe is more in the context.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I just read in [Make WordPress Core](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/24/last-week-in-wordpress-core-9/) that the kitchen sink parameter should be coming back in 3.9.1 very soon.

Comment: link,unlink don't show any buttons in 3.9.1 on tinymce

Comment: @helgatheviking right, see the answer, she have the hint to this issue.

Answer (score 6):

One change is that:

`theme_advanced_buttons1` is going to be changed to:

`toolbar1` which allows you to update the buttons so my new function will look something like:

```
function myformatTinyMCE( $in ) {
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'bold';
    $in['toolbar2'] = 'formatselect';
    return $in; 
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
```

Also it looks like `formatselect` is not really favored as much in this iteration. Should probably be converting over to `styleselect` as it allows more options and customizations (such as nested styles) and also goes with a more minimalist design.

Another *gotcha* is alignment options have been changed from `justify` to `align` like so: `alignleft, aligncenter, alignright, alignjustify`.