# TinyMCE 4.x : How to customize toolbar on wp_editor()

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

Since upgrading to Wordpress 3.9 (which includes TinyMCE 4.x), I have problems customizing the editor, displayed via `wp_editor()`

In the example below, I want to disable the 'fullscreen' button, but this doesn't work.

```
 $settings = array(  'textarea_name' => 'description',
                 'quicktags' => false,
                 'media_buttons' => false,
                 'teeny' => true,
                 'tinymce'=> array(
                 'theme_advanced_disable' => 'fullscreen'
                       )
);
wp_editor( $content, 'description', $settings );
```

Unfortunately, the [documentation for TinyMCE API 4.x](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aindex) isn't as helpful to me as the 3.8 one

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress 3.9 - Trouble Editing new TinyMCE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137986/wordpress-3-9-trouble-editing-new-tinymce)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

replace

```
'theme_advanced_disable' => 'fullscreen'
```

with

```
'toolbar1'=> 'bold,italic,underline,bullist,numlist,link,unlink,forecolor,undo,redo'
```

Also, remove `'teeny' => true,`

Comment: I had to keep `'teeny' => true,` in order for this to work

Answer (score 0):

adding this filter below your code you can delete fullscreen button or another with `teeny=>true`, deleting items from `$buttons` array (fullscreen is 14 counting from left to right from 0 )

first remove from $settings

```
'tinymce'=> array(
             'theme_advanced_disable' => 'fullscreen'
)
```

and add filter

```
add_filter( "teeny_mce_buttons", "gk_comment_form_no_fullscreen");
function gk_comment_form_no_fullscreen($buttons) {
    unset($buttons[14]);
    return $buttons;
}
```

Comment: Please don't dump code barely, add some explanation how this code can help etc.